# How to go to specific tab bar view via 3D Touch quick items

Tags: ios, swift, ios12, 3dtouch

I'm trying to go to any out of the 3 tab bar elements that I have in my storyboard depending on which quick action I select when 3D Touching on the app icon. I want to still be able to see the tab bar controller, which is where I've been struggling recently. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I have got it to go to each separate Tab Bar Items.

I now need to activate the segue in each view, and here is the code that I'm using:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let myTabBar = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
    let NavigationController = UINavigationController.self
    if shortcutItem.type == "com.LukeB.Quick-Actions-Test.Three" {
        myTabBar?.selectedIndex = 2
        //Need to go to the segue with identifier SegueThree
    }
    if shortcutItem.type == "com.LukeB.Quick-Actions-Test.Two" {
        myTabBar?.selectedIndex = 1
        //Need to go to the segue with identifier SegueThree

    }
    if shortcutItem.type == "com.LukeB.Quick-Actions-Test.One" {
        myTabBar?.selectedIndex = 0
        //Need to go to the segue with identifier SegueOne


    }
}
```

Comment: After `let myTabBar = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController`. What does `myTabBar` evaluate to?

Comment: Well they just go to different views associated with tab bar items 0,1 and 2

Comment: So the views are transitioning correctly? I'm not understanding what the problem is

Comment: At the moment, When I 3D Touch on the app and go to quick icon, it goes to the VC that is associated with `myTabBar?.selectedIndex = x`.  However I need to perform a segue that goes to another ViewController and end up on that one instead of the tab bar Item x.

Comment: I see. Do you want the tab bar to stay visible after the transition?

Comment: Yes absolutely.

Comment: Ok. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are looking for is explained in the documentation for `UIApplicationDelegate`'s quick action handler [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622935-application). To summarize, you need to check the launch options in your `willFinishLaunching` or `didFinishLaunching` and then decide what to do based on what you see.

The issue you're having could be caused by how you are setting the view that is first shown in your app. You might be setting the ViewController to the one that is nested into the tab view controller rather than setting it as the tab controller and then telling the tab controller which of its views to show.

That's just speculation, you'll need to share more code to get a more specific answer.

**Update:** Now that you have solved the problem of having the correct tab show, you want that view to segue another view on top of it.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller) for `UITabBarController` gives some hints for how to do this in the section called "The Views of a Tab Bar Controller". One way to do what you are trying to do would be to set up your `UIViewControllers` so that each tab has a navigation controller as a root. This way, you can push whichever controller you want onto the view in a way the user will recognize.

```
     UINavigationController - Controller 1 -> push new controller
    /
TBC - UINavigationController - Controller 2 -> push new controller
    \
     UINavigationController - Controller 3 -> push new controller
```

Alternatively, if you have a custom segue you want to use, you can continue with what you are doing with `myTabBar?.selectedViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`

Comment: Well I don't have any code.... everything I tried didn't work.  However, I used .present to present the view controller, but then the tab bar controller at the bottom disappeared.  I just need the same but with the tab bar controller visible at the bottom.

Comment: @YachtSamba Show us, what you tried so far. And you’ll get an answer.

Comment: I'm confident that I could help you more if you provide the line of code that you used with `.present` that didn't work. @YachtSamba

Comment: Ok - well now I have got it to go its different Tab Bar Icon, but I need to do the segue that is linked to that view.  I'll put my code in.

Comment: So is there still a problem?

Comment: Thanks - but when I use `myTabBar?.selectedViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` it crashes with the error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<UINavigationController: 0x116845800>) has no segue with identifier 'segueOne''`

Comment: That means that you haven't set up the segue on whichever view controller you are calling this function on. You need to have configured it in the storyboard. If you did set up the segue in the storyboard and you're not sure where to go from there, can you tell me about the hierarchy of your views?

Comment: Well I set the identifier for the segue, and ctrl+dragged from the button to the other View Controller.

Comment: So are you trying to segue when a button is pressed or when the quick action happens?

Comment: Yes I want the segue to happen from the tab bar to the navigation controller when the button is pressed (that works) and when the quick action happens (which only takes me to the tab bar controller where there is the button)

Comment: Are you talking about the button at the bottom of the screen that is inside the tab bar, or a button that you have created in your view controller?

Comment: I've created a button for the segue to go to the second View Controller.

Comment: What I've tried to do is `MyTabBar.selectedViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueOne", sender: nil)` after `MyTabBar.selectedIndex = 0`  to perform the segue that is on the `selectedViewController`but then I get the error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<UINavigationController: 0x15781d200>) has no segue with identifier 'SegueOne''`

Comment: Try `(MyTabBar.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueOne", sender: nil)`. The problem is probably that the segue is from your view controller, not the navigation controller

Comment: Wow you are amazing :)  - that works - thank you so much!